# Rails Gateway GEM daemon: find and kill the process in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, ssh, proxy

I'm using this GEM: https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh-gateway

It creates a gateway and proxy that listens on defined port `localhost:1080`

I'm a little bit confused about how to detect a gateway (if so) and proxy daemon, as the gateway is open until `!shutdown` command is given. My code is very raw and sometimes it throws errors. When I'm trying to run it one more time I'm getting an exception that notifies that a gateway is already open. I want to kill it manually using `htop`

How to grep a gateway daemon and kill it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service is called **dnsmasq**
and it's easy to filter with **htop** and kill